# "contrib" scale in PCA plot

Tags: r, pca, pearson-correlation, pearson

What does the `contrib` scale indicate in `PCA` plot?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Contains the contributions (in percentage) of the variables to the principal components. The contribution of a variable (var) to a given principal component is (in percentage) : (var.cos2 * 100) / (total cos2 of the component).*

[Source](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/)